# NETSH - How to import WIFI profile when WIFI NIC is not present

Tags: windows-10, deployment, netsh

I'm currently in process of creating standardised Winndows 10 image for kisok PC.

Now the problem I'm facing is that during install, when I try to preload WIFI profile using `netsh wlan add profile file=C:\wifi.xml user=all`, I get the error stating that `There is no wireless interface on the system`. Now the error itself makes sense, since USB WIFI adapter is physically not yet connected to the PC (we connect adapters to the PCs when they are mounted into kisok stand, OS install is done way beforehand).

I've already tried adding *fake* WIFI adapter using "Add legacy hardware" option in device manager, but unfortunately that didn't fool netsh into thinking that WIFI is present.

Is there any way other way I can preload WIFI profile into my image when there is no WIFI adpater connected or trick that would convince netsh that WIFI card is present when actually it is not? Maybe using WISM or some other tool?

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?  Have you tried using your command, then adding the adapter?  Is there a profile there?

Comment: In the sense of exit code it's not an error - exit code of netsh command in task sequence is 0.  I've tried using command after TS was complete and when no adapter is plugged in it prints on stdout the above mentioned message and profile does not get installed. When I plug in WIFI adapter and than re run the add profile command, than the profile is installed and the PC gets connected to SSID configured in profile.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider making profile creation part of Wifi installation/configuration process.  In other words, move this task to after the hardware is installed.  If your 'image' is deployed using a task sequence in configuration manager, my suggestion is to move this task to after the target system boots and loads the drivers.

Comment: It's already in state restore step of TS, so drivers are installed and loaded. I guess I could display something like "Please insert WIFI dongle " on screen and pause TS before Install WIFI profile step, but that would put me one step further from zero touch installation.

Comment: Add the requirement for the dongle to be inserted before installation. You may check the return code of netsh and only display that dialog if the dongle is missing.